# remove part of string with replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, int

I'm trying to delete the beginning of the following sentence from a file:

> size:
>
> size :

The issue is with the space between "**:**". I have tried many regular expressions using some help from https://regex101.com/ but none of them works for me.

**My code:**

```
String myString= in.nextLine();
myString.replaceAll("size$:", "");
int n = Integer.parseInt(myString);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex `size\s*:` which mean replace size followed by zero or more spaces followed by `:` like so :

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("size\\s*:", "");
```

---

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ZHXaw/1)

---

Note that Strings in Java are immutable so you have to assign the result of replaceAll to your String else `myString` will not be changed even your replaceAll work fine.

---

If you want to delete only the `"size\s:"` strings from the beginning of your line, you can just add `^` anchor to your regex which mean beginning of line, so it will be like this :

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("^size\\s*:", "");
```

---

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u3SQBh/1)

Comment: Fine! The most obvious erring consisted in the forgotten assignment of the replacement's result. That's why all regexes failed.

Comment: Sorry I don't get you @JoopEggen

Comment: As opposed to the OP you are assigning: `myString = myString.replaceAll...`.  The failure of every regex tried might stem from not ssigning to myString.

Comment: This is correct @JoopEggen I was in my way to edit and add this information in my answer

Comment: I should have waited a bit. ;) So I am not the only one post-editing.

Comment: Its ok @JoopEggen thank you very much, I add it to my answer :)

Comment: This will delete all of the "Size:" strings from the text, while the OP asks for deletion of the string on the beginning of the sentence.
So, the sentence _Size : some text random size: some text_ will become _some text random some text_. I am not sure if that is what OP wanted.

Comment: @Dvorog I add another part in my answer which answer your question :)